# Trying to serve image dynamically from GAE, getting 404

Tags: python, google-app-engine

My image isn't being served form the datastore, I am getting a 404 on the page where the image should be.

Here is the code:

```
import cgi
import datetime
import urllib
import wsgiref.handlers

from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.api import images
from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app


class PropUpload(db.Model):
  property_name = db.StringProperty()
  property_address = db.StringProperty()
  project_type = db.StringProperty()
  building_size = db.StringProperty()
  stories = db.StringProperty()
  space_available = db.StringProperty()
  per_leased = db.StringProperty()
  prop_image = db.BlobProperty()
  date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)


class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    self.response.out.write("""<!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="en">
              <head>
      <somehtml>""")

    display2 = db.Query(PropUpload)
    display2.order("-date")
    for dis in display2:
        self.response.out.write('<div><img src="img?img_id=%s"></img>' % dis.key())
        self.response.out.write('<h4>Property Name: %s </h4><br>' % dis.property_name)
        self.response.out.write('<div style="border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;">Address: %s </div><br>' % dis.property_address)
        self.response.out.write('<div style="border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;">Type:  %s ft<sup>2</sup></div><br>' % dis.project_type)
        self.response.out.write('<div style="border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;">Stories:  %s </div><br>' % dis.stories)

    self.response.out.write("<more html>")


class Image(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    img_id = self.request.get("img_id")
    dis = db.get(self.request.get("img_id"))
    if dis.prop_image:
      self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = "image/png"
      self.response.out.write(dis.prop_image)
    else:
      self.response.out.write("no image")


class UploadPage2(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    self.response.out.write("""<!DOCTYPE html>
    <form action="/upload2" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                        <div><label>Property Name:&nbsp</label></div>
                        <div><textarea name="prop-name" rows="1" columns "100"></textarea></div>
                        <br><br>
                        <div><label>Property Address:&nbsp</label></div>
                        <div><textarea name="address" rows="1" columns "100"></textarea></div>
                        <br><br>
                        <div><label>Property Type:&nbsp</label></div>
                        <div><textarea name="prop-type" rows="1" columns "100"></textarea></div>
                        <br><br>
                        <div><label>Building Size:&nbsp</label></div>
                        <div><textarea name="size" rows="1" columns "100"></textarea></div>
                        <br><br>
                        <div><label>Stories:&nbsp</label></div>
                        <div><textarea name="stories" rows="1" columns "100"></textarea></div>
                        <br><br>
                        <div><label>Space Available:&nbsp</label></div>
                        <div><textarea name="title" rows="2" columns "100"></textarea></div>
                        <br>
                        <div><label>Percent Leased:</label></div><span>
                        <div><textarea name="percent" rows="3" cols="100"></textarea></div><br>
                        <div><label>Picture:</label></div>
                        <div><input type="file" name="img"/></div>
                        <div><label></label></div><span>
                        <div><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></div>
                      </form>""")


  def post(self):
    props = PropUpload()
    property_name = self.request.get('prop-name')
    property_address = self.request.get('address')
    property_type = self.request.get('prop=type')
    building_size = self.request.get('size')
    stories = self.request.get('stories')
    space_available = self.request.get('space')
    prop_image = self.request.get('img')
    per_leased = self.request.get('percent')
    props.property_name = property_name
    props.property_address = property_address
    props.property_type = property_type
    props.building_size = building_size
    props.stories = stories
    props.space_available = space_available
    props.prop_image = db.Blob(prop_image)
    props.per_leased = per_leased
    props.put()
    self.redirect('/upload2')


application = webapp.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
    ('/upload2', UploadPage2),
    ], debug=True)


def main():
  run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Everything works fine, except for the 404, and I can't finding anything googling the issue.

Thanks for the help, and sorry if I left anything out, I will edit anything in.

Comment: What does your `app.yaml` look like? Specifically, what do you have set up to handle requests to `img`? Assuming it looks like `/img`, try prefacing `img?img_id=%s` with a `/`.

Comment: it is /images, but I was under the impression the images are served directly from the datastore?

Comment: Ah, totally right man, my bad - spaced while reading :) I'll take another (closer) read through.

Comment: Also, does `self.response.out.write(""")` appear in your code as it does roughly in the middle of the code above?

Comment: No, there is just plain html code where that is, I was just trying to save space on the page

Comment: Can you also include your WSGI handlers as defined in your script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your uploading works properly, you need to provide a handler for the images themselves. Right now you are referencing `<img src="img?img_id=%s">`, but `img` doesn't appear to resolve to anything in your handlers (also, you don't need to supply a closing `</img>` tag to the `<img>` attribute in HTML). What you want to do is set up a handler for image-based requests and have the response be the image itself. You already have `Image` set up for what appears to be that purpose (note that you will likely want to replace the `no image` part with an actual image so the result type is consistent).

In order to map the `Image` handler to a URL, try modifying your handlers as follows:

```
application = webapp.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
    ('/img', Image),
    ('/upload2', UploadPage2),
    ], debug=True)
```

This will now route requests to `/img` to the `Image` handler (you may also want to change your `src` tag to `<img src="/img?img_id=%s">`, where it should then locate and return your image.

Comment: AHH, its always that last step with me. You're the best, thanks!

Comment: @Kevin No worries man - you had already done the hard work :) Good luck with everything!